# WPF DataGrid selected row stays highlighted even when user clicks another control

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Is it possible to turn off the selected row highlighting when a user clicks another control in the window?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `SelectedIndex` to `-1` in the `LostFocus` event, thus losing the selected item and removing the highlight.

Comment: Thanks this works to a certain extent - however it only works if I click on another focusable control - I wonder if trying to make everything else on the window focusable would help..